# validate login using flask mysql not working

Tags: python, mysql, flask, authentication

i'm creating a web app using flask. my validate login is not working in the sense it always says wrong username or password.
i have hashed the password using the python library.
i have attached the code below.

app.py

```
    _username = request.form['inputEmail']
    _password = request.form['inputPassword']



    # connect to mysql

    con = mysql.connect()
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('sp_validateLogin',(_username,))
    data = cursor.fetchall()




    if len(data) > 0:
        if check_password_hash(str(data[0][3]),_password):
            session['user'] = data[0][0]
            return redirect('/userHome')
        else:
            return render_template('error.html',error = 'Wrong Email address or Password.')
    else:
        return render_template('error.html',error = 'Wrong Email address or Password.')


except Exception as e:
    return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))
finally:
    cursor.close()
    con.close()
```

TABLE DESC

```
CREATE TABLE `BucketList`.`tbl_user` (
`user_id` BIGINT not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`user_username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`user_password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`));
```

validate login procedure(MYSQL)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_validateLogin`(
IN p_username VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
select * from tbl_user where user_username = p_username;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: there are two places where your code enters Wrong Username and Password statements. one when your `len(data) <= 0` or when `check_password_hash` condition fails. You need to identify which condition it is. for debugging you can use `ipdb`, or you can go by good old `print` statements to identify which statement is failing.

Comment: password hash is longer than your 64 characters. so a `full hash` is generated, but it doesn't get it's way to your table, just its first 64 characters are saved. so you never have equal hashes. i think this is the code just by looking at it. check this too.

Comment: hey senaps! thanks that was the issue!